# swift request coredata and delete

Tags: swift, core-data

i would like to request all my core data where the "mhd" field >= the date of today. this code works fine:

```
 func DatenAbrufen() {

    let calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
    let AktuellesDatum = calendar.startOfDayForDate(NSDate())
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "LM_ITEMS")
    fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "mhd >= %@", AktuellesDatum)




        if let fetchResults = managedObjectContext!.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest, error: nil) as? [LM_ITEMS] {
            lebensmittel = fetchResults
        }
}
```

how can i delete in this query all other data, where "mhd" is not >= date of today?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to support iOS 8.x, or OS X Yosemite, or older, you'll need to fetch each object and then delete it. Write another predicate that is the opposite of the one you have. Execute that fetch request. Then iterate over the found objects and send each one a `deleteObject`. Save your managed object context. This can take quite a while, if you're deleting lots of objects.

For iOS 9 and El Capitan, you can use `NSBatchDeleteRequest`, described in [WWDC 2015 session 220](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2015/?id=220). For large numbers of deleted objects, `NSBatchDeleteRequest` is much faster. You're not loading each object into memory just to delete it. You also bypass some validation rules, and must refresh your MOC for it to see changes–which might be undesired consequences, depending on your usage.